# How to change SQL Authentication to Windows Authentication in BDC Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-addin, authentication, bdc

Sharepoint 2007
Created a BDC Access SQL Server as following

```
Authentication Mode: Passthrough
DBACcessProvider: sqlserver
Integrated Security: empty
User Name: username
Password: password
```

This is working fine. Now, I need to connect to the SQL database using windows authentication. How could do this in BDC?